# Handle MouseEvent.CLICK, MOUSE_DOWN in subclasses

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mouseevent, uicomponents

I'm building a panel of buttons, that are enclosed in Canvas container. For this purpose I created a `MyButton` class, which is a subclass of UIComponent. MyButton class has 2 other subclasses: `MyRadioButton` and `MyMenuButton`, which have another behavior on `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`. `MyMenuButton`creates and shows a menu, that I build from XML and it builds ok.

I add listeners in the superclass like this:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
```

It's done at the creation stage.

In my subclasses I override `handleMouse` handler.

```
override protected handleMouse(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
  // subclass specific handling
}
```

These button objects are added to canvas container as following:

in class `MyButtonsContainer.as`:

```
this.rowChildren.addChild(button);
```

These buttons draw perfectly and in place. The problem is the behavior:
The event doesn't come to handleClick handler of superclass. And that's the question actually - why can it be? 
Thanks in advance

EDIT: It appears that MOUSE_DOWN & MOUSE_UP interfere with CLICK event. When I remove listeners to them I get to click handler.How to cause them live together?

Comment: Are you defining handler in child classes, show some relative child code.

Comment: Look inside of question: "In my subclasses I override handleMouse event..."

Comment: In your shared code are overriding a "Handler-Function"  named "handleMouse", which will be trigger on parent event, i.e. "MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN" and "MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP", do you have any "event-handler" in subclasses? clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to catch `CLICK` event as timing difference between `MOUSE_DOWN` & `MOUSE_UP`.

EDIT: A short/long explanation: For some reason my listeners for `MOUSE_DOWN/MOUSE_UP` events were interfering with `MouseEvent.CLICK`. I was suggested by somebody to give up on listening to `MouseEvent.CLICK` and instead start a timer in `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and check again the timer in `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP`. If the difference less than 0.1 (you can put there another threshold) then it was a click actually.

Now some sample code:

```
public class MyButton extends UIComponent
{
   ...
   private var _clickTime : Number = 0.;

   public function void MyButton()
   {
       super();
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse);
       addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
   }

   protected function checkForClick(event:MouseEvent) : Boolean
   {
      var down : Boolean = event.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN;

      if (down)
         _clickTime = getTimer();
      else {
          var diff : Number  = getTimer() - _clickTime;
          if (diff/1000. < 1.) {
              handleClick();
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
   }

   protected function handleClick(event:MouseEvent) : void
   {
       // handle the click here
   }

   protected function handleMouse(event:MouseEvent) : void
   {
       checkForClick(event);
       ... 
       // take care of your button graphic state
   }
```

**DISCLAIMER**: This code works for me and good for me and my application needs. If you disagree with this way or have a better way to suggest, please do it in comments. Since this answer answers my own question and this EDIT was added only because I was asked to do so, please don't downvote it if you don't agree with it.

Comment: This answer is hard to understand for people browsing already asked and answered questions - could you elaborate more..?

Comment: Downvote translates to "this answer is not useful". At the moment if someone comes across this when trying to solve the same problem, it's not going to be useful to them. Will upvote once you fix it :P

Answer (score 0):

call the superclass method like so

```
override protected handleMouse(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
  super.handleMouse(event);
  // subclass specific handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just need to make sure that in your overriden handlers you end each one with a call to super -

```
override protected handleMouse(event:MouseEvent):void {
// my logic here for the subclass
trace("blah blah blah");

//now redispatch up to the superclass.
super.handleMouse(event);

}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that I don't override CLICK event handler in subclasses and it doesn't come there. That's is the question. Why it comes to MOUSE_DOWN/UP handler and doesn't come to CLICK event handler?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I'd override click actions like this..

Base class:

```
public class MyButton extends UIComponent
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function MyButton()
    {
        // listeners
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
        // ...other listeners
    }

    /**
     * Called on dispatch of MouseEvent.CLICK
     */
    private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        doClick();
    }

    /**
     * Override this method and fill with actions to
     * do when this is clicked
     */
    protected function doClick():void
    {
        trace("base class was clicked");
    }
}
```

And the extending class:

```
public class MyOtherButton extends MyButton
{
    /**
     * Override doClick
     */
    override protected function doClick():void
    {
        super.doClick();
        trace("extending class was clicked");
    }
}
```

---

After closely inspecting your code:

You've added two different listeners to one function for one, shouldn't these have seperate functions as they are called by contrasting events?

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouse);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouse);
```

Also, it seems like you're expecting handleMouse to be fired by a click event judging by the below code, which isn't the case.

```
override protected handleMouse(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
  // subclass specific handling
}
```

Either that, or you're forgetting to override `handleClick` as well - which is the method that you're running on a click event. You possibly need to add this code:

```
override protected handleClick(event:MouseEvent) : void
{
  // subclass specific handling for a click
}
```

Comment: tried, this doesn't work for some reason. It's like it doesn't get CLICK event at all

Comment: It's possible that something is over the target, like a transparent object?

Comment: NO, but I found out, that when I remove MOUSE_DOWN & MOUSE_UP the click works. So probably they interfere somehow. How to make them work together?

Comment: Actually one sec, let me add to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't get neither to handleClick of superclass nor to that of subclass. Once I remove listeners to MOUSE_DOWN/MOUSE_UP it comes to handleClick. That's right that it's the same handler that handles MOUSE_DOWN/UP, but I'm querying it but asking about event.type and the GUI works fine.

Comment: Shrug, all I can think of is that somewhere in your inheritance you've done something wrong.